# Get-VMMemory powershell return problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell

I am trying to use ASP.NET to return the total startup RAM on a VM on a Hyper-V server.  The function I have is this:

```
    public static double GetRamVM(string vm, string host)
    {
        string cmdToRun = "get-vmmemory -name " + vm + " -computername " + host + " | select Startup" ;
        var shell = PowerShell.Create();
        shell.Commands.AddScript(cmdToRun);
        var mem = shell.Invoke();

        foreach (PSObject obj in mem)
        {

            var startMem = obj.Members["Startup"].Value;

            return (double)startMem;
        }

        return 9999.9999;
    }
```

However, whenever I return it - it ALWAYS returns as 9999.9999.  I know that the command works, as when I run it manually in a powershell window I get the result that I want.

Please help - as I am going out of my mind.

Edit:
The manual run of the script looks like this

```
PS C:\Users\mark> Get-VMMemory -vmname "test test" -computername "testhost" | select Startup

                                                                                     Startup
                                                                                     -------
                                                                                   536870912
```

Comment: Why do you have this then `return 9999.9999;`?

Comment: Debug your code. If `mem` contains no elements, chances are it's a permission issue.

Comment: It isn't permissions (the application pool identity this uses is the same as what i run the manual script as).  Also, if I just dump out a mem.ToString() it returns System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]

Comment: So, what is `obj.Members["Startup"].Value` of the first element of `mem`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the `-ExpandProperty` on the PowerShell `Select` cmdlet. This will return a number for the account of memory being used and not an `PS-object`, so you wont have to extract the value in your C code.

```
public static double GetRamVM(string vm, string host)
{
    string cmdToRun = "get-vmmemory -name " + vm + " -computername " + host + " | select -ExpandProperty Startup" ;
    var shell = PowerShell.Create();
    shell.Commands.AddScript(cmdToRun);
    var mem = shell.Invoke();

    return (double)mem;
}
```

Comment: That worked - I also found a small error in my syntax in the C# code in that I was using -name and not -vmname (all other cmdleets use -name!?!)